# Script with every Incoming email

Tags: email, applescript, rules

I am new to applescript and I am running into an issue.
I have setup a rule in mail to check incoming mails and trigger a script. What do I need to change in the script below ? The problem is in the script not the rules.
The script will not go beyond what I have below until I select it myself.
What would be the right code so I don't have to actually select the email.
Thanks.

```
tell application "Mail" -----check mail for incoming emails
set theMessage to message 1 of mailbox "INBOX" of account "GMAIL"
set thebody to content of theMessage
set theSelection to selection
set theMessage to item 1 of theSelection
content of theMessage
end tell
```

Answer (score 1):

The basic syntax for a mail rule is

```
using terms from application "Mail"
    on perform mail action with messages theMessages for rule theRule
        repeat with aMessage in theMessages
            set thebody to content of aMessage
            -- do other things with aMessage
        end repeat
    end perform mail action with messages
end using terms from
```

The script must be saved in `~/Library/Application Scripts/com.apple.mail/`, then you are able to select it in the dialog window to create and edit a rule.

Comment: mmmh. I appreciate the help, but as I stated, I am fairly new to this.
I would have loved to have my poorly written script, rewritten the right way.
I know it sounds like being lazy, but it would take me a long time to figure it out. I usually do try to figure it out, but I kind of need this fairly quickly.
I hope that someone has a bit of time to help me.
Thanks.

Comment: You can't use `selection` in rule scripts, actually even no user interaction at all. The event handler passes a list of received mails in the `theMessages` parameter, In the repeat loop you can process each single message.

Comment: The variable `thebody` contains the content of the message. It's just plain text. Since we don't know exactly what you're going to accomplish state you question more precisely or ask a new question with more information.

Comment: I need to extract the first 2 words of the content and assign a variable to each of the word. (myword1 and myword2)

Comment: Never mind. I guess I don't know how to explain. thanks for trying to help.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you are asking, you just need to add the following lines to vadian's answer (replacing "-- do other things with aMessage")

```
set myword1 to the first word of body
set myword2 to the second word of body
```

There are lots of good resources for learning AppleScript at [MacOSX Automation](https://macosxautomation.com/applescript/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help.
I guess that was what I needed at the time.
I found a workaround by just having Automator mark the message as read.
That did the trick to trigger my script automatically as soon as the message comes in.